# How to make a color plot of a matrix in r

Tags: r

[The plot between e_values and r_values, the values of probabilities of fp0 indicated by different colors of my color scale.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beGyU.png)I have a matrix which has 132 rows and 3 columns.The names of the are e_values, r_values and fp0.Now how do I plot a color plot of my matrix?The plot must have e_values on the  y-axis and r_values on the x-axis and the various values of fp0 as the colors.The e_values vary from 0 to 0.5 in the intervals of 0.1 and the r_values vary from 0 to 6.5, in the intervals of 0.5 till 4 and then 0.2 from 4 to 6.5 and my fp0 values are basically my probabilities and so they vary from 0 to 1.I couldn't figure out the way to upload my csv file and so I gave a description of my matrix and am also printing my matrix.I am also quite new to R and quite unfamiliar with the way the packages like ggplot2 and similar others work, so it will be very helpful if I get a detailed explanation.

```
      e_values   r_values   fp0
    1   0          0         1.0000
    2   0.1        0         1.0000
    3   0.2        0         1.0000
    4   0.3        0         1.0000
    5   0.4        0         1.0000
    6   0.5        0         1.0000   
    7   0          0.5       1.0000  
    8   0.1        0.5       1.0000 
    9   0.2        0.5       1.0000
   10   0.3        0.5       1.0000
   11   0.4        0.5       1.0000
   12   0.5        0.5       1.0000
   13   0          1         1.0000
```

My matrix goes on in the above manner until r=4, after which the subsequent r values increase by 0.2 and the fp0 values also start to show variation.
and this pattern is followed till the no. of rows become 132.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use fp0 as color in your ggplot.

The code below will create the plot you described. Here, darker colors indicate higher probabilities. If you have a discrete probability, you could also use distinct colors for each level (second plot).

```
require(ggplot2)

e_values = seq(0, 0.5, by = 0.1)
r_values = c(seq(0, 4, by = 0.5), seq(4.2, 6.5, by = 0.2))

df <- data.frame(e_values = sample(e_values, 132, replace = T),
                 r_values = sample(r_values, 132, replace = T),
                 fp0 = runif(132))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = r_values, y = e_values, color = fp0))
g <- g + geom_point()
g

df <- data.frame(e_values = sample(e_values, 132, replace = T),
                 r_values = sample(r_values, 132, replace = T),
                 fp0 = sample(seq(0, 1, by = 0.2), 132, replace = T))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = r_values, y = e_values, color = as.factor(fp0)))
g <- g + geom_point()
g
```

[image: Continuos probabilities]
[image: Discrete probabilities]

Edit: The picture you uploaded has r_values as y axis and e_values as x axis. Additionally, the shape of the points is different. Here is the code to produce the desired plot:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = e_values, y = r_values, color = fp0))
g <- g + geom_point(shape = 15, aes(fill = fp0))
g
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Niko, I've tried plotting as you said but I don't seem to get what I desired.The plot doesn't match with my matrix values.The name of my matrix is M1 and I have edited my post as I think that I could not convey my query effectively. Please consider having a look at my revised post and then suggest me something to do.Thanks again.

Comment: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (132): x, y, colour
This is what I am getting.What did I miss.

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a plot showing the desired output (maybe a mockup or example).

Additionally, a point plot might not be the best way to visualize your data. However, only you can decide which method is as we don't know the meaning of the variables

Comment: I have added the photo which can be accessed by the link right at the first line.So, basically I have two iterated maps which I am running for several iterations.Both the maps follow the same equation of dynamics and my e_values are the coupling factor between the maps and r_values is my non linear parameter.I am calculating fp0 as the no. of times either of the maps converge to the 0 fixed point for a large time,for a given e and r and for various initial conditions.Hope,this helps.

Comment: I changed the plot according to your photo. Have you been able to solve the error msg yet? 

If yes it would be good if you could add the first few lines of your data frame to your question.